# Phing: Accessing the value attribute in <condition> tag

Tags: phing

Trying to learn Phing, by converting Ant Build.xml to Phing. Can't seem to find a search function on Phing User doc....

This is what I have:

```
<condition property="script-suffix" value=".bat" else="">
<os family="windows" />
</condition>

<echo message="Script-suffix is ${script-suffix}" />
```

There are two problems that I need to fix but I don't know how:

1. I don't know how to convert this
   condition into Phing acceptable. The
   `else=""` attribute is
   causing an error.
2. I cannot access the
   `script-suffix` property
   using `${script-suffix}`

I've tried `${project.script-suffix}`, `${phing.script-suffix}`, `$, and other obvious combination. And attempted to change the condition using the <if>, <else>` tag and failed spectacularly T__T.

Thank you in advance ^__^.

Answer (score 1):

```
<condition property="script-suffix" value=".bat">
<os family="windows" />
</condition>

<if>
<equals arg1="${script-suffix}" arg2=".bat" />
<then>
<os family="windows" />
</then>
<else>
<property name="script-suffix" value="" />
</else>
</if>
<echo message="---- Build Properties ----" />
<echo message="" />

<echo message="OS is ${os.name}" />
<echo message="Basedir is ${project.basedir}" />

<echo message="Script-suffix is ${script-suffix}" />

<echo message="" />
<echo message="---- Storefront Properties ----" />
```

Ah I think I got it, I don't have a window machine to test the window os option though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<property name="script-suffix" value="" />
<condition property="script-suffix" value=".bat">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

or

```
<condition property="script-suffix" value=".bat">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
<condition property="script-suffix" value="">
    <not>
        <os family="windows" />
    </not>
</condition>
```

For me your code returns (Phing 2.6.1)

```
BUILD FAILED
Error reading project file [wrapped: os (unknown) doesn't support the 'family' attribute.]
```

besides, I looks to me that you can't use `<property />` task nested inside `if` conditions.

Comment: I was also converting a working build file from ant to Phing and your first suggestion worked perfectly, thanks